# Is running time depend on the size of an input?

Tags: xml, xsd, ocaml, coq

I have a parser function written in OCaml, then I have an input file is .xsd, the output is a Coq format.

I tested my parser with two different input (`.xsd`), one has `60.2KB` size and another has `121.0KB` (size). I used `time` to return the running time and here is the result:

xsd has `60.2KB` takes: `user: 0m2.792s`

xsd has `121.0KB` takes: `user : 0m37.838s`

It is clearly that the time depend on the size of the input file.

I have a silly question just want to make sure that is the running time indeed depend on the size of input file?

In my parsing function I used a lot of function has structure for example:

```
let  genr_type b = function
| Elt (n, Some t, _, _) -> ...
| Group (n, Some t, _, _) -> ...
| ... -> ...
```

is it make the parser takes more time?
Thank you very much

Comment: Without any explanation what your "parser" does, none can answer your parser run time depends on the input size, or some other factors of the inputs.

Comment: It's fairly reasonable to assume that if your're reading each character of a file and doing stuff, more characters will take more time

Comment: I think he is suggesting that the running time of the parser is not _linear_ in the size of the file. More information please lykimq!